# Rewrite a file throughout GIT history?

Tags: git

I've been looking for a shortcut way to change text in a file throughout history, lets say I had a contributor that I added, or something of the sort

```
$ diff README.md README.md.new
28a29,32
> ## Contributors
>   - ehime     [Jd Daniel]
>   - thatgguy  [Someone Else]
```

So normally what I'd do is remove a file completely from all of history using filter-branch:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter     \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch README.md' \  
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This would evidently nuke the entire history of my file, including tags etc then `mv README.md.new README.md` and my regular git push stuff... ok no bueno no i have tags and commits that no longer have that file...

So , how can I rewrite this line through the entire history of the file? I think we can avoid glob protection as well, but I'm uncertain....

I don't believe BFG can do this, since it's specifically geared towards cleaning not rewriting?

This is extremely handy when we have for instance, an API endpoint that changes or a static / elastic ip that will need to be reflected across all points in history for testing etc.

Comment: If you devise a workflow that relies on routine rewriting of history, you're going to have a bad time.  I'd take a moment to look at more industry-standard approaches to solving the issues you mention.

Comment: Understood, but not the issue nor the policy i put in place ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (maybe) achieve what you want, but let's start with this:

> how can I rewrite this line through the entire history of the file?

Consider this philosophical question: suppose I tell you that instead of 1993-2000 = Clinton presidency, 2001-2008 = GWBush presidency, it was actually 1993-2001 = Clinton, 2002-2008 = Bush.  Suppose further that I somehow hypnotize you to *believe* this.  Have I actually *changed* history, or are you just using *wrong* history?  What if somehow everyone else believes it too?

With that in mind, consider this fact: *no Git commit can ever be changed* because the hash ID of a commit is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of that commit, which includes the files in the snapshot that the commit holds forever.  However, *any Git commit can be copied to a new, somewhat different commit* that has a different hash ID.

So: what if we copy *every* commit to a new, slightly different one, resulting in a new, different repository, and then somehow convince everyone that this new, different repository is the *real* repository and they were all using fake history before?

That's what `git filter-branch` does: it copies every commit<sup>1</sup> to a new one, applying whatever filter(s) you specify first.  The new commit has a new, different hash ID if anything about it is even one bit different from the original—and of course as filter-branch copies, if it's made a change to a previous commit, the next commit that gets copied has to change its parent hash ID so that it uses the *copied* commit instead of the original.  So as soon as there is any change anywhere, this ripples down through the rest of history.

The result is that your repository now holds *two sets of commits*—two complete histories—and if you've changed the very first commit's copy, these two sets of commits are disjoint.  (If you left that very first commit alone, the two sets—the two histories—join up at the start, and then diverge wherever you made your first change.)  Filter-branch rewrites your branch names, and perhaps tag names (`--tag-name-filter`), so that they refer to this new history.  Your repository now believes in the new history, not the old one.  (The `refs/original/` names remember the original history; once you delete them, the original commits become vulnerable to the garbage-collector.)

You must now convince *everyone* to switch.  This is a big [flag day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_day_(computing)).

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, more precisely, every *reachable* commit based on the `git rev-list` style arguments you pass to `git filter-branch`.  Also some filters omit some commits entirely, on purpose, so that the copied history has fewer commits than the original.

---

#### The filter mechanisms

The simplest filter is `--tree-filter`.  This filter works by literally extracting each commit into a temporary directory, then running whatever command(s) you provide, in that temporary directory.  So you could use:

```
--tree-filter /tmp/edit-readme.sh
```

where /tmp/edit-readme.sh is your (executable) program that edits `README.md` in place.  Note that we use an absolute pathname here (`/tmp/edit-readme.sh`) since Git is in some mysterious unknown temporary directory when it runs your tree filter.  (Even if you use `-d`, Git creates subdirectories within whatever argument you used.)

The disadvantage of this filter is that it's extraordinarily slow.  It takes a long time to extract, modify, and rebuild *every* commit.  You can use filter-branch's `-d` option to use an in-memory file system, which will speed it up a lot, but you will need enough memory to unpack and rebuild every commit.

The fast filter for this is `--index-filter`, but it's tricky to use: filter-branch copies each commit *only* to the index.<sup>2</sup>  Your job is then to *modify the index*.  You can inspect the index for the presence of a `README.md` file, and if it exists, extract it, modify it, and put the new one back into the index.  Git makes the new commits from whatever you leave in the index, after your index filter.

I leave it to you to write the index or tree based edit script.  You now have the tools to rewrite your repository into a new, incompatible repository.  Whether you can force everyone else to abandon their existing repositories in favor of this new one, so that they will believe the fake history, is another question entirely.

Comment: also thanks for the humor, it had me nodding and laughing pretty much the entire post